# Поиск по базе SQLite в Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Здравствуйте, хотел реализовать такую идею, сделать поиск по ключевым словам по базе данных sqlite в Android. Например: клиент вводит в edittext слово или буквы, после этого нажимает на button и тут уже будет поиск по базе, есть ли в таблицах слово == edittext, если есть то  id этого поля будет записываться на массив или вроде этого, что бы в конце выводили результаты, где есть с ключевым словом edittext.

Comment: Рад за Вас, а вопрос то в чём?

Comment: да кстати, как можно реализовать эту идею? как можно эту написать в программном виде?

Comment: пиши программу, базу, поиск по базе, написать можно :)

Comment: Я это делал, и скажу со стопроцентной уверенностью, что это пишется на джаве.

Comment: как ты делал? какие функций использовал? посоветуй мне пожалуйста, алгоритм какой? я вот только только начинаю изучать джаву и хотелось бы написать такую программу

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать классы из Android SDK, в частности нужно использовать класс SQLiteOpenHelper, который идёт в поставке сдк. Но без знания java всё равно далеко уйти не получится. Вот статья, в которой неплохо описана работа с этим классом http://idev.by/android/311/ . Весь материал Вам от туда не нужен, только по поводу этого класса.